# Numeric Timestamp in Kafka Oracle JDBC Connector

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect

I'm currently trying to setup a JDBC Connector with the goal to read data from a Oracle DB and push it to a Kafka topic using Kafka Connect. I wanted to use the "timestamp" mode:

> timestamp: use a timestamp (or timestamp-like) column to detect new and modified rows. This assumes the column is updated with each write, and that values are monotonically incrementing, but not necessarily unique.

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#mode

```
{
       "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
       "dialect.name" : "OracleDatabaseDialect",
       "connection.url": "XXX",
       "connection.user" : "XXX",
       "connection.password" : "XXX",
       "mode" : "timestamp",
       "quote.sql.identifiers": "never"
       "timestamp.column.name" : "LAST_UPDATE_DATE",

       "query" : "select a1.ID, a1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, b1.CODE
                    from a1
                    left join b1 on a1.ID = b1.ID
        ...
}
```

My problem is, that the timestamp on the database is defined as NUMBER(15), e.g. 20221220145930000. The Connector creates a where statement at the end of my defined query like

`where a1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > :1 and a1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE < :2 order by a1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE asc` 
This leads to an error message: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP

Unfortunately, the database is not under my control (proprietary software). I have only read permissions.
Is there a possibility to set the timestamp type in this connector? I already tried to use the (to_timestamp() function directly in the SQL-statement and a SMT ([timestampConverter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html)) without success

Comment: any update about this issue please ?